# TableViewCell Only Returns Nil

Tags: ios, swift

I'm having trouble identifying why a tableViewCell keeps returning nil. This is the chunk of code I'm almost certain is causing the problem.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CollectionCell", for: indexPath as IndexPath) as? CollectionViewCell

    if cell == nil {
        var nib = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("CollectionCell", owner: self, options: nil)
        cell = nib![0] as? CollectionViewCell
    }

    if cell == nil {
        cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CollectionCell") as! CollectionViewCell
    }

    // ...

}
```

This is the whole CollectionViewCell file as requested.

```
class CollectionViewCell: UITableViewCell {
@IBOutlet weak var txtNameCollection: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var btnGoToCollection: UIButton!

@IBOutlet weak var imgShelf: UIImageView!

@IBOutlet weak var btnNameCollection: UIButton!

@IBOutlet weak var btnEditCollectionName: UIButton!

@IBOutlet weak var imgNameCollection: UIImageView!

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
}

override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}
```

}

Comment: Have you registered cell with `tableView.register(_:forCellReuseIdentifier:)`? Also, what is CollectionViewCell? Isn't it a subclass of `UICollectionViewCell`?

Comment: Those two `if` conditions are wrong. They shouldn't be there. The only thing that you have to use in this method to get a cell is `tableView.dequeueReusableCell()`. So your first line is completely fine. You need to find out why the cell is `nil` after that.

Comment: 1. Why do you have things named "CollectionCell" in a table view? 2. Why are you using the very out-of-date, Swift 2 signature for `cellForRowAt`?

Comment: You should share code and xib of CollectionViewCell.

Comment: if you're using xib, you should consider using storyboard and [prototype cells](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html). And as @nguyen-hoan already said, you need to provide [more informations](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

```
   override func viewDidLoad() {
          super.viewDidLoad()
          tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "CollectionCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "CollectionCell")
   }

   func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

       //var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CollectionCell", for: indexPath as IndexPath) as? CollectionViewCell
       var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CollectionCell" ) as? CollectionViewCell

       cell?.txtNameCollection.text = "Text"
       return cell

       You have to delete this because you use Xib File. And you dont do prototype cell on storyboard. There is no need. Just create a tableView with name is tableView
   //    if cell == nil {
   //        cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CollectionCell") as! CollectionViewCell
   //    }

   //    if cell == nil {
   //        var nib = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("CollectionCell", owner: self, options: nil)
   //        cell = nib![0] as? CollectionViewCell
   //    }

   }
```